# Wrong close reason shown

Tags: bug, status-norepro, close-reasons

The question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50373/what-dont-do-latex-text-composition shows that it is closed by me (and others) as “not constructive”. I did however vote to close it as a duplicate of [Best practices references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577/best-practices-references). So the question now gives a wrong representation of my vote (I am of the opinion, that the actual question (“Is there a list of LaTeX best practices?”) is interesting, and we shouldn't close as “not constructive” because of bad English).

Comment: This has sort of been discussed on meta.SO: [Distinguish votes to close by reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/170190).

Comment: @Jarrod: Showing wrong information is a bug, not a feature request.

Comment: Yet another instance of wrong closing information: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51158/?noredirect=1 -- I just voted to close this question, but I wasn't given any option to migrate. It is implied that I think this question is on-topic on another site just because I said it's off-topic here. (In this case, it was correct though.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce the close reasons issue with the current build of our network sites. Please let me know if the problem remains for you.

Comment: Well, 2.5 years might have made this difficult to reproduce.

Comment: @percusse totally. Better late than never, as they say!